# How do I check a text file in js to see if it is empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a text file in my directory and need to check if it is empty. I have attempted fs.readFile("users.txt").isEmpty(). How do I approach this?

Comment: What's `isEmpty()` supposed to be? Or you could check filesize unless you care about whitespace, or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use this, a simple promise-based approach to check if the file is empty, optionally also checks if the file only contains whitespace. A file that only contains whitespace might also be considered as empty.

The downside, of this approach, is it reads the file entirely, this may not be the most efficient way to accomplish this if the file is really large.

```javascript
const fs = require('fs')

function isFileEmpty(fileName, ignoreWhitespace=true) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
            if( err ) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }

            resolve((!ignoreWhitespace && data.length == 0) || (ignoreWhitespace && !!String(data).match(/^\s*$/)))
        });
    })
}


isFileEmpty('users.txt')
  .then( (isEmpty) => {
    console.log( "empty:", isEmpty) // true or false
  })
  .catch( (err) => {
    console.log("error reading the file");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fs.readFile("users.txt", (err, file) => {
    if(file.length == 0){
        console.log("file is empty")
    }else{
        console.log("file is not empty")
    }
})
```